# What's with Battlefield 4's range toggling on sniper rifles?

Tags: battlefield-4

I was playing through the campaign and when I first wielded a sniper rifle a tutorial popup appears at the top-right corner of the screen, explaining something about bullet drop distance and the alternate fire key (the key to toggle single fire/burst fire/auto fire on automatic rifles).

I was in the heat of a gun fight so I didn't have the time to read through the popup, but then I noticed if I press the alternate fire key with a sniper rifle, there is a distance indicator at the bottom of the screen in place of the fire mode, and I can toggle it between 0m, 100m, 150m (I don't remember the exact number).

I'm wondering if anyone read through that tutorial bubble and can tell me what that means, I searched online but there's no information regarding this, and I don't wanna play through my campaign again just to read that bubble...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is the zeroing mechanism. This means that if you have it zeroed at 500m, the cross-hairs are dead on at 500m. This allows you to make distance shots much easier. If you were to zero the scope at 500m and shoot at a target at 100m, your shot would hit much higher than your cross-hairs. Previously, your only option was to compensate for bullet drop by aiming high and guessing between mil dots, which made distance shots on moving targets much more difficult. If you have your scope properly zeroed, now you can just offset the horizontal reticule the appropriate lead for motion.

Comment: Yup that's the thing, I actually deleted my save accidentally and had to play through the campaign again... And in turn read through that bubble this time lol

Comment: This could use a diagram for the hard of understanding, like myself.

Comment: That's 500m horizontal, right?  So if you're on a skyscraper with your sights set at 500m and the target is exactly 500m away, you'll actually have to aim **lower** than the target to compensate for the decreased bullet-drop, correct?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - yes. This can be noticed to an extreme case when you are directly over someone. It's very hard to tell where the bullet will hit then

Comment: If you are directly over someone, I guess you can just set the number to 0m and aim straight down. Bullet drop is insignificant in that case :P

Comment: `which made distance shots on moving targets much more difficult` Actually, hitting moving targets is still difficult, even with your rifle properly zeroed, since you have to account for the time it will take for your bullet to hit its target.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the zeroing on the scope is for countering the drop in trajectory a round experiences in horizontal flight at great distances . if you are stood on a tall building and the target is a great distance away the scope still needs to be zeroed at the exact distance as decreased bullet drop is barely noticeable !!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article I read that explains bullet drop mechanics (and other sniping techniques in BF4) I personally found it to be extremely helpful:

http://www.respawnless.com/battlefield-4-multiplayer-guides/sniping-aim-accuracy/

One last thing - note the section of the article where he talks about the Milliradian dots on the crosshair when zoomed in. Understanding and utilizing how these are supposed to be used will GREATLY improve your skills as sniper when shooting from extremely long distances.

Comment: Can you summarize the information in the article, please?  That way, your answer is still good in the event the website goes down.  Besides, it saves people a click.